# Should I overwrite rack with rackup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update to the latest version of Rails and getting the follow error:

```
➜  ~ gem update rails
Updating installed gems
Updating rails
rackup's executable "rackup" conflicts with rack
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    "rackup" from rackup conflicts with installed executable from rack
```

Should I replace rack with rackup?

**System info**

```
➜  ~ ruby --version
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]

➜  ~ rails --version
Rails 7.0.8

➜  ~ sw_vers -productVersion 
14.1

➜  ~ uname -v
Darwin Kernel Version 23.1.0: Mon Oct  9 21:28:45 PDT 2023; root:xnu-10002.41.9~6/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020
```

Comment: If you've never used this executable before, it's a non-issue.

Comment: Looks like a version issue. Starting with `rack` 3, the `rackup` executable was extracted into a gem with the same name. Updating `rack` from 2.x to 3.x should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my Ubuntu 23.10 installation. After reading the comments on your question, I interrupted the `rails` install and installed the `rackup` gem. Opening a new shell and rerunning `gem install rails` completed without the issue.

### Installed `rackup` gem

```
$ gem install rackup
rackup's executable "rackup" conflicts with rack
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  y
Successfully installed rackup-2.1.0
Parsing documentation for rackup-2.1.0
Installing ri documentation for rackup-2.1.0
Done installing documentation for rackup after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

### Also updated RubyGems

```
NOTE:
A new release of RubyGems is available: 3.4.14 → 3.4.22!
Run `gem update --system 3.4.22` to update your installation.

$ gem update --system 3.4.22
. . .
```

### Afterwards `rails` 7.1.2 installed without error:

```
$ gem install rails
. . .
$ rails -v 
Rails 7.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have multiple rack gems with this command.

> gem uninstall rack
> and you see this :

1. rack-2.2.4
2. rack-3.0.9
3. All versions

Choose one of them or uninstall all. (reinstall them)

If it doesn't work, you probably have two files with the same name in local. To fix that, find them and rename one of them.

> where rack